# Can I capture by reference a returned value?

Tags: c++, lambda

If a lambda captures by reference a value that will be returned along with the lambda. Does the reference holds when calling the lambda?

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct context_with_callback {
    bool flag = false;
    std::function<void()> callback;
};

std::unique_ptr<context_with_callback> make_context() {
    auto ctx_with_callback = std::make_unique<context_with_callback>();
    ctx_with_callback->callback = [&] () { 
        ctx_with_callback->flag = true; 
    };

    return ctx_with_callback; // am I allowed to do that?
};

int main() {
    auto ctx = make_context();
    ctx->callback(); // will this be always valid?
    return 0;
}
```

If it is not valid, I could capture the raw pointer by copy instead, but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: It seems to run fine in valgrind and with usban because of RVO

Comment: RVO may allow this to work at runtime, but it feels to me that this is undefined behavior, since the lambda is capturing a reference to a local `unique_ptr` variable that goes out of scope when `make_context()` exits. Why not have the lambda capture a reference to just the `flag` directly instead? Since the lambda will not outlive the `context_with_callback` object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will simply capture the flag instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Wouldn't that introduce sneaky bugs if someone ends up copying the `context_with_callback` object? The copy could outlive the flag that it refers to - not to mention that it refers to something other than itself.

Comment: @eerorika well it's the same as OP's code currently does (capture the instance).

Comment: @eerorika right now, the code captures a `unique_ptr` by ref and stores the lambda in the object's `callback`. The lambda does not outlive the object, but it can outlive the ref'ed `unique_ptr`. Capturing a ref to the `flag` member should be safe. But, if someone made a copy of the object, and thus a copy of the lambda, then the captured ref is also copied. That is a problem whether the ref is to an object pointer or to the object's `flag`. It could never be reseated to ref the copied object/flag. A new lambda capturing the new object/flag would have to be assigned to that's object `callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "can" capture an automatic variable by reference, but that won't be useful if you return the lambda because the reference will dangling as soon as the function returns.

> ```
> return ctx_with_callback; // am I allowed to do that?
> ```

Technically yes, but it won't be useful.

> ```
> ctx->callback(); // will this be always valid?
> ```

This is never valid given the current implementation.

---

This would work, and would even allow returning the context by value, avoiding dynamic allocation if you so prefer:

```
struct context_with_callback {
    bool flag = false;
    std::function<void(context_with_callback&)> callback_object;
    
    void callback() {
        callback_object(*this);
    }
};

context_with_callback make_context() {
    return {
        .flag = false,
        .callback_object = [](context_with_callback& ctx_with_callback) { 
            ctx_with_callback.flag = true; 
        },
    };
}
```